# Issues while trying to build a hibernate Criteria query that navigates through a many-to-many association with a join table entity and composite key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three entities: Account, AccountAttribut and Attribut. Account and Attribut are associated via AccountAttribut in a many-to-many relationship like it is described [here](http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/).

The question is: Why can't I use: "aa_pk.attribut" as a property name to navigate through the association tree? Because this is the property name, I defined in my AccountAttribut entity, isn't it?

Can you help me with this issue?

These are relevant code extracts:

Account:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    private Long accountId;
    private List<AccountAttribut> accountAttributes = new LinkedList<AccountAttribut>();
    private Person person;
    private Zielsystem zielsystem;

    public Account() {
    }
    // ...
}
```

AccountAttribut:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account_attribut")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="aa_pk.account", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="account_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="aa_pk.attribut", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="attribut_id"))
})
public class AccountAttribut {}
private AccountAttributPk aa_pk = new AccountAttributPk();

@Column(name="wert")
private String wert;

@EmbeddedId
public AccountAttributPk getAa_pk() {
    return aa_pk;
}

public void setAa_pk(AccountAttributPk aa_pk) {
    this.aa_pk = aa_pk;
}

@Transient
public Account getAccount() {
    return getAa_pk().getAccount();
}

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    getAa_pk().setAccount(account);
}

@Transient
public Attribut getAttribut() {
    return getAa_pk().getAttribut();
}

public void setAttribut(Attribut attribut) {
    getAa_pk().setAttribut(attribut);
}

public String getWert() {
    return wert;
}

public void setWert(String wert) {
    this.wert = wert;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this== o) return true;
     if (o ==null|| getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

     AccountAttribut that = (AccountAttribut) o;

     if (getAa_pk() !=null?!getAa_pk().equals(that.getAa_pk()) : that.getAa_pk() !=null) return false;

     return true;
}

 public int hashCode() {
     return (getAa_pk() !=null? getAa_pk().hashCode() : 0);
 }
}
```

AccountAttributPk:
**Updated** this code. Added: @Embeddable Annotation. Forgot that. But still the same errors.

```
@Embeddable
public class AccountAttributPk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1551814445010872872L;
    private Account account;
    private Attribut attribut;

    @ManyToOne
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Attribut getAttribut() {
        return attribut;
    }

    public void setAttribut(Attribut attribut) {
        this.attribut = attribut;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        AccountAttributPk that = (AccountAttributPk) o;

        if (account != null ? !account.equals(that.account) : that.account != null)
            return false;
        if (attribut != null ? !attribut.equals(that.attribut)
                : that.attribut != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (account != null ? account.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (attribut != null ? attribut.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The CriteriaQuery:

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.criteriaList(
   session.createCriteria(Account.class).
      createCriteria("accountAttributes").
         createCriteria("aa_pk.attribut").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("name"))
);
```

The Exception:

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)

I tried the following solutions:

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.criteriaList(
   session.createCriteria(Account.class).
      createCriteria("accountAttributes","accAttrAlias").
       createCriteria("accAttrAlias.aa_pk","accAttrAAPKAlias").
         createCriteria("accAttrAAPKAlias.attribut", "attrAlias").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("attrAlias.name"))
);
```

Java Errorlog:
org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: accountAttributes.aa_pk

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.criteriaList(
   session.createCriteria(Account.class).
      createCriteria("accountAttributes","accAttrAlias").
         createCriteria("accAttrAlias.aa_pk.attribut", "attrAlias").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("attrAlias.name"))
);
```

Java Errorlog:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Hibernate Errorlog:
"Hibernate: select this_.account_id as account_1_3_4_, this_.person_id as person_i2_3_4_, this_.zielsystem_id as zielsyst3_3_4_, accattrali1_.account_id as account_3_4_0_, accattrali1_.attribut_id as attribut2_4_0_, accattrali1_.wert as wert1_4_0_, person5_.person_id as person_i1_2_1_, personenat6_.person_id as person_i3_2_6_, personenat6_.attribut_id as attribut2_8_6_, personenat6_.person_id as person_i3_8_6_, personenat6_.attribut_id as attribut2_8_2_, personenat6_.person_id as person_i3_8_2_, personenat6_.wert as wert1_8_2_, zielsystem7_.zielsystem_id as zielsyst1_9_3_, zielsystem7_.name as name2_9_3_ from account this_ inner join account_attribut accattrali1_ on this_.account_id=accattrali1_.account_id left outer join PERSON person5_ on this_.person_id=person5_.person_id left outer join person_attribut personenat6_ on person5_.person_id=personenat6_.person_id left outer join zielsystem zielsystem7_ on this_.zielsystem_id=zielsystem7_.zielsystem_id where attralias2_.name is not null
Feb 20, 2014 11:25:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
Feb 20, 2014 11:25:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'attralias2_.name' in 'where clause'"

Comment: yes, have a look at the new code, i posted

Comment: from your query it looks like `attralias2_` is not being mapped at `person_attribut` some thing is wrong will try to work it out today and let you know

Comment: Thx dude, i need that quite bad.

Comment: BTW try this in mean time `createCriteria("accAttrAlias.attribut", "attrAlias").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("attrAlias.name"))` as I will be able take detail look on day end.

Comment: Then i get: "org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: attribut of: AccountAttribut"

Answer (score 0):

the criteria should be like this variable

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.criteriaList(
   session.createCriteria(Account.class).
      createCriteria("accountAttribute","accAttrAlias").
         createCriteria("accAttrAlias.ATTRIBUTE_VARIABLE_NAME", "attrAlias").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("attrAlias.name"))
);
```

here is `Criteria` [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)

**Update**

Logic creating criteria is you can directly create Restrictions on properties that are associated with Entity on which the criteria is created `.createCriteria(THIS_ENTITY.class)` but if there is another entity associated, then you can create `alias` to reach its properties for `Restriction`. So from your updated post criteria should change to

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.criteriaList(
   session.createCriteria(Account.class).
      createCriteria("accountAttribute","accAttrAlias").
       createCriteria("accAttrAlias.aa_pk","accAttrAAPKAlias").
         createCriteria("accAttrAAPKAlias.attribut", "attrAlias").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("attrAlias.name"))
);
```

Check this [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-associations) related to associations, hope you will understand it's usage.

In case of embedded component

```
List<Account> queried_accounts = HibernateUtils.criteriaList(
   session.createCriteria(Account.class).
      createCriteria("accountAttribute","accAttrAlias").
         createCriteria("accAttrAlias.aa_pk.attribut", "attrAlias").
            add(Restrictions.isNotNull("attrAlias.name"))
);
```

Comment: What should i use to replace ATTRIBUTE_VARIABLE_NAME? Is it "aa_pk.attribut"? Because this doesn't work either. Still the same Exception.

Comment: Ok, i posted the AccountAttribut without imports.

Comment: Hm, i tried your new code and it happened to be a step further towards a solution. But now i get the Exception: "org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: accountAttributes.aa_pk". Im not sure about the meaning of that. BTW: I changed a property name in Account from "accountAttribute" to "accountAttributes"!

Comment: Ill do so later this day. Thx in advance for your effort till now. But i suppose that the new solution wont work either.

Comment: Still does not work. Have a look at my main post for further information.